# Textual analysis in R

Tags: r, analysis, sentiment-analysis, textual

I am confused about the correct usage of sentiment analysis in R.
I want to do a textual analysis using the postive / negative list provided by Loughran and McDonald (https://sraf.nd.edu/loughranmcdonald-master-dictionary/).

Previous research says that stemming of the documents under analysis is required. I already performed the stemming.
The question I have now: Can I use the sentiment list on the text like they are or do I need to stem them as well?

For me it doesn't make sense to use the complete words on a stemmed document, since R wouldn't detect the words. However, I saw other research doing it.

Can somebody explain to me, what I have to do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include libraries you are working with or link to concrete guide you are following as workflows can be quite different.  With [quanteda.sentiment](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda.sentiment/), which already includes _LoughranMcDonald_ dictionary, you could just do something like `textstat_polarity("I am confused about the correct usage of sentiment analysis in R.", dictionary = data_dictionary_LoughranMcDonald)` , for example (returns -1.09).